# Potential check-in/boarding problems with one-way ticket to USA?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, one-way

My family and I are New Zealand (NZ) citizens and legal residents of Mexico.  We are currently in NZ, and are due to return to Mexico via a one-way flight to the US (LAX) and driving to Mexico.  We have B1/B2 visas for the US.

When we first moved to Mexico we travelled under ESTA and were required to have onward tickets from the US (this was required at the airport in NZ, it was not an issue when we arrived in the US).

If we try to check-in at Auckland Airport to the US are we going to run into this same requirement now that we have the B1/B2 visas?  Will the airline allow us to board without an onward ticket?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an onward ticket to enter the US if you travel on a visa. It is only necessary if you are traveling under the Visa Waiver Program. You should have no problem with the airline, as Timatic (the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents) makes it clear that the return/onward ticket is only necessary when using VWP.

> Visa required, except for Nationals of New Zealand with a
>   biometric passport (with an electronic chip symbol on the
>   cover) and an Electronic System for Travel Authorization
>   (ESTA). They must travel as a tourist, on business or in
>   transit, for a maximum stay of 90 days. (SEE NOTE 60190)
>
> NOTE 60190: Passengers must have a return/onward ticket.

When a country requires onward tickets of all travelers of a given nationality, even with a visitor visa, Timatic will show the following text: "Visitors not holding return/onward tickets may be refused entry." This is *not* present for this nationality/destination pair.

Comment: Could you add a quote from timatic into your answer for future reference?

Comment: @JonathanReez You want me to quote something that isn't there?

Comment: @MichaelHampton "as Timatic... makes it clear..." - I'm confused about what you've quoted after that, it isn't clear to me regarding people holding visas (like we do), the quote seems to only be referring to people entering using ESTA, which is why I asked the question to start with.

Comment: @Midavalo That is the whole point! It does not apply to you.

Comment: @Midavalo You can check Timatic yourself via https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&country=/MX

Comment: @MichaelHampton So where does it make it clear that it won't be an issue for me?  It basically says "Visa required... except if you have ESTA.  See note, which says you need an onward ticket".  To me that doesn't tell me that I *don't* need an onward ticket?  Is there anywhere that actually says that I'm good to go with a visa?

Comment: I used the link provided by @Traveller, there wasn't anywhere to specify that I already had a visa (that I could see, at least)

Comment: @Midavalo The note applies to people travelling on ESTA. It does not apply to you.