# Can I enter the US with a one way ticket with a B1/B2 visa?

Tags: transit, b1-b2-visas, jfk, proof-of-onward-travel, one-way

Can I enter the US with a one way ticket? I have a B1/B2 visa but I’m not staying in the US. I’m a university student and I’m traveling to my college in Europe. I did not buy a return as I’m not sure when I would be returning. I’m basically just transiting through JFK for a few hours before my flight leaves for Europe. Would a one way ticket be okay in this instance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Potential check-in/boarding problems with one-way ticket to USA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/134034/potential-check-in-boarding-problems-with-one-way-ticket-to-usa)

Answer (score 5):

You don't need specifically a return ticket, but an onward ticket, ie a ticket that shows you will be leaving the US within the limit of stay of your visa. Your ticket to Europe serves that purpose.

Comment: It's not applicable in this case, but for others, if you're travelling to Canada or Mexico via the US, then you also have to have a ticket to leave Canada and Mexico, unless you are a citizen of either, or have a long-term visa / permanent residency, or a ticket out of US/Canada/Mexico

Comment: Actually you don't even need that.  A return/onward ticket is NOT a requirement for entering with a B1/B2 visa (although it is when entering using VWP)

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  An onward ticket is a statutory requirement for travel under the visa waiver program.  There is no such requirement for travel with a B visa.